# Where is this text coming from at the end of my checkout URL?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, magento2.3.1, routing

I'm adding a "buy now" button to my site.  I'm using the code from [here](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow).

When I click the button, my site tries to go to `example.com/checkout/#93=4`, which then results in it going to `example.com/checkout/noroute`.  Where is the `#93=4` part coming from?  I've tried to step through the Magento code in a debugger, and as far as I can tell, the extension is trying to go to `example.com/checkout/`, and I can't figure out what's adding the `#93=4`.  But I'll be honest; I don't understand Magento's routing.

Here are the parts of the code that I think are relevant:

**buynow.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    return function (config, element) {
        $(element).click(function () {
            var form = $(config.form);
            var baseUrl = form.attr('action'),
            buyNowUrl = baseUrl.replace('checkout/cart/add', 'buynow/cart/add');
            form.attr('action', buyNowUrl);
            form.trigger('submit');
            form.attr('action', baseUrl);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

**Add.php**

*I've used the debugger to verify that the line `$baseUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl();` towards the bottom of the code does return `example.com/checkout/` (no `#93=4`)*

```
class Add extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{
    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()]
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            if (!$product) {
                return $this->goBack();
            }

            $cartProducts = $this->_objectManager->create('Test\BuyNowButton2\Helper\Data')
                             ->getConfig('buynow/general/keep_cart_products');
            if (!$cartProducts) {
                $this->cart->truncate(); //remove all products from cart
            } 

            $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );

            if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                $baseUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                            ->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
                return $this->goBack($baseUrl.'checkout/', $product);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: without going through all of the code I would suggest it related to the product information being appended to the URL.  Seems like others have had this issue as well https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow/issues/25